# Remove row from Vuejs datatables

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatables

On the laravel application, I have a page which shows a populated datatable (using [this dependency](https://github.com/pstephan1187/vue-datatable)). Each row on the datatable I have a delete button that deletes the object in that row using an axios http request to my server to delete. It works, and that's great - however I have trouble finding a way to delete the row of the datatable of the resource I just deleted from the DOM.

For instance, this is my delete function:

```html
axios.delete(`/admin/queries/${id}`);
                    $(this.$el).fadeOut(400,()=>
                        flash('Query deleted successfully'));
```

Obviously the $(this.$el) deletes the entire table. How can I delete the individual row?

For reference, my datatable is equivalent to this [one](https://designrevision.com/demo/shards-dashboards/transaction-history.html) :

[Example, how can I access say object at index 1 and delete/remove it from the data?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l59Yq.png)

Thanks :)

**UPDATE**
I can access the index data by $vm0._props.data[index=2] but there is no delete / remove option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use something like the following in your template code:

```
<datatable :columns="table_columns" :data="table_rows"></datatable>
```

And your row Object has for example the id property:

```
{ "id": 0, "subject": "test" }
```

You can delete a row (with id 9 for example) using:

```
let deleteIndex = this.table_rows.findIndex(item => item.id === 9);
this.table_rows.splice(deleteIndex);
```